# Testimonials - to have or to not have

Tags: testimonials

My current site has testimonials on the homepage, but I am hoping my new site looks so good its design is credible enough, and having testimonials might cheapen the feel. I mean you dont see testimonials on Apple's site. I want the site to create the credibility not a list of platitudes from people know one has heard of.

Or do testimonials really add to credibility of a product? Its in the B2B industry if that helps.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was flagged as *primarily opinion based* when there are lots of studies on the subject

Comment: The credibility of a website is based on a number of different factors, one of which is the presence of social proof, and testimonials is a popular form of social proof which can be difficult to verify. However, if the rest of your website is credible enough, then it will potentially enhance the effect of the testimonial.

Comment: Also see this related question about photos on websites: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/105801/does-personal-photo-on-the-website-improve-its-credibility

Comment: The point about Apple is irrelevant because Apple is a well-established company that spends millions if not billions in advertising every year in order to avoid having to publish testimonials on its site. The vast majorities of companies in the world are *not* Apple, *do* have to publish testimonials and while I haven't seen the studies @Devin refers to, I would hazard a guess that consumers see it as the norm rather than the exception.

Answer (score 5):

Testimonials can work very well if they're done right.

Don't plug testimonials just because you want to have them somewhere. Testimonials should be carefully picked.

A few things to consider,

**Try to include testimonials from people your visitors will recognize.** A testimonial from John the IT guy from XYZ is not going to make your visitors trust your brand. But a testimonial from a client working for a company that people will recognize is far more effective and builds trust.

**Don't over do it, keep it simple.** Don't overload your site with testimonials. Nobody is going to read all of that. Don't have testimonials which are very long. Your visitors should be able to grasp it quickly.

**Pick the most effective testimonials.** Don't pick testimonials which says the same thing. Pick testimonials which praise different aspects of your services.

Comment: first one is the big one.  I definitely dismiss testimonials from random people as invented nonsense that make the site not to be trusted, If they're from a legit company and I can verify you've actually worked with them....then good

Answer (score 1):

There is one deciding factor to your question that is: **Are you a product or service that has many competitors. If yes, you need to show testimonials** because they provide a sense of confidence to your new customers.

For instance, a prototyping product/tool like [Principle](http://principleformac.com/) and [balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/); to get new customers to buy these products they have to display testimonials on their websites, while thinking about Apple.com they are not selling just an iPhone, there is a range of products they sell which is why Apple doesn't display any testimonials on its website but **an e-commerce portal like Amazon / eBay where a specific product of Apple is sold - they have the user reviews there which act as testimonials**.

Answer (score 1):

testemonials may be a relevant thing to use if:

- you have prestigious users within your market niche using the apps or products you are developing
- you have meaningful responses in terms of people that have a great deal of know how of the topic your product addreses
- those will be on a proper section that may be:

  - a division within the frontpage;
  - a division within the about or similar page;
  - a specific page or section meant for the purpose, usually placed at 2/4-3/4 of the menu item contents;

please consider to make such kind of section:

- small;
- direct;
- organized;
- clean;

please consider to:

- detach the section using:

  - background colors;
  - text colors;
  - text fonts;

in any of these cases consider to:

- use neutral elements;
- do not use excentric elements;